# 960 grid border confusion.

Tags: css, layout, 960.gs

I'm hoping this is something simple and just my inexperience with css.  I'm simply trying to add a single pixel border to a group of nested divs.

```
<div class="grid_11 suffix_1">
  <div class="borderupdown">
    <div class="grid_1 alpha">
      <p>RNK</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_1">
      <p>IQ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_8 omega">
      <div class="grid_8 alpha">
        <p>title<p>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="grid_8 omega">
        <p>comments stuff here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the borderupdown css

```
.borderupdown
{
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

The class borderupdown is simply a 1px border top and bottom. My "understanding" is that since the other divs are nested under that class it should create a 1px border top and bottom of all of that. Instead I get both borders showing up visually on top with the 2px margin between them.  I'm totally confused as to why.  ( In case it matters I'm using a fluid version of the 960 grid system.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've stumbled onto the issue where elements floated within a container aren't included in the dimensionality of the container.  (I'm sure other folks have a better way of wording that...).  Floated elements are not included in the calculation of the dimensions of any container by default.  What you're looking for is called a "clearfix".  Check out this post for a very nice, detailed list of fixes: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: Brian, Thank you.  I'm not even going to pretend I understand why, but it works.  Thank you very much.